# How To Implement "Territory" Concept in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, crm, hierarchy, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using SuiteCRM and I've created five Users. How can I structure those Users in a hierarchical levels?

**Sales Manager**

- user1
- user2

**Production Manager**

- user3

**Sales Manager** and **Production Manager** are also Users.

Here user1 and user2 should be under control of Sales Manager and user1 records should not seen by user2 and user2 records should not be seen by user1.

user3 should be under control of Production Manager.

In some cases, I want to use SuiteCRM to handle multiple divisions of the same company. I also want to restrict the data access as per the divisions.

This whole concept is called 'territory'. I want to use 'territory management' in my SuiteCRM instance. Please tell me how to do territory in SuiteCRM.

Answer (score 0):

What about using build in SecurityGroups and ACLRoles? You could set up four groups.

- Sales Manager Group
- Sales Manager User Group
- Production Manager Group
- Production Manager User Group

With those and the appropriate settings you should be able to archive your goal.